# Setting up a QMainWindow's corner to belong to a docking widget area (QMainWindow::setCorner) using Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

Well, subj.

I use dock widgets in my desktop Qt4 application, but I don't like the layout the docks form. I want the *right* dock to occupy the *upper right* corner which is by default occupied by the *top* dock.

I've googled (*seriously!*) what can I do with this and I've found [an article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405543&seqNum=5) where the use of `QMainWindow::setCorner` is described. It is pretty simple, and I've ended up with the following code that I've added to my window's constructor:

```
this->setCorner(Qt::TopRightCorner,Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

It works perfectly, but here comes my question.

The code seems to describe the UI in the application's *logic* code section, which is, I think, not quite good. In my case the UI is described using `.ui` files I create with Qt Designer, so the UI things are separated from the application's main logic things.

The question is, is there a way to make Qt generate such code from `.ui` files?

The second reason is that the form in Qt Designer looks different from what I get when I run the application (this behavior is perfectly legal and obvious, of course).

If I'm unclear, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: @Tay2510 it's just... in Designer the upper right corner is occupied by the top dock widget, and in the runtime it is occupied by the right dock (that's what I want and what I've got by calling `setCorner`).

Comment: Well Designer is surely limited. If you know that Qt has to offer in terms of widgets, layouts and size policies you may as well write UI in C++ and separate it from logic by using your own project structure and get some benefits from it. Doing everything by designer seems to be impossible indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Qt generates C++ header file `ui_foo.h` from  `foo.ui`(XML file format) through UI compiler(uic) during the time qmake is working. In other words, eventually those `.ui` files will inevitably become part of your *logic* code, and it's quite normal to interact with those UI instance in code editor.

Personally, I feel Qt Designer's job is helping create a basic body of chiffon and leaving the rest of decoration to *logic* code, depends on personal appetite so you can add your own flavor and make it a delicious cake. That's why I started to use Qt Creator, which allows me to switch back and forth between the built-in UI designer and code editor. Hence, though I like the way of how Qt Designer simplifies the programming, I'd rather take it just as a supporter.

Let's just say the ability of Qt Deisgner is limited. For example , it's almost impossible to make a table with clickable button only by Qt Designer:
[image]

In brief, it is not worthwhile to seek a way to make Qt generate such code from `.ui` files because it depends on how UI complier is designed. Just code it!